# How are lifetimes of struct arguments treated in calls to functions with lifetime parameters?

Tags: rust

This code passes the compiler (for clarification lifetimes are not elided):

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    _field: &'a i32,
}

fn test<'a, 'b, 'c>(_x: &'a mut Foo<'c>, _y: &'b bool) {  // case 1
}

fn main() {
    let f = &mut Foo { _field: &0 };
    {
        let p = false;
        test(f, &p);
    }
}
```

If I use `'b` instead of `'c` in `test`'s definition like so:

```
fn test<'a, 'b>(_x: &'a mut Foo<'b>, _y: &'b bool) {  // case 2
}
```

the code fails to compile ("p does not live long enough")!

What I would expect to happen at the call of `test` in case 2 is:

- `'a` is set to the actual lifetime of `f`,
- `'b` is set to the intersection of the `Foo`'s actual lifetime and `&p`'s actual lifetime which is `&p`'s lifetime,

and everything should be fine, as in case 1.

Instead, what actually seems to happen in case 2 is that `'b` is forced to become the lifetime of the `Foo` which is too big for `&p`'s lifetime, hence the compiler error 'p does not live long enough'. True?

Even stranger (case 3): this only fails if `test` takes a &mut. If I leave the `<'b>` in, but remove the `mut` like so:

```
fn test<'a, 'b>(_x: &'a Foo<'b>, _y: &'b bool) {  // case 3
}
```

the code passes again.

Anyone to shed light on this?

Cheers.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to the Rust Users Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-are-lifetimes-of-struct-arguments-treated-in-calls-to-functions-with-lifetime-parameters/1599?u=shepmaster)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting the difference with `mut` was a key observation. I think that it will make more sense if you change the type of the second argument and give one possible implementation:

```rust
fn test<'a, 'b>(_x: &'a mut Foo<'b>, _y: &'b i32) {
    _x._field = _y;
}
```

This function has the ability to mutate `_x`. That mutation also includes *storing a new reference* in `_field`. However, if we were able to store a reference that had a **shorter** lifetime (the intersection you mentioned), as soon as the inner block ended, the reference in the `Foo` would become invalid and we would have violated Rust's memory safety guarantees!

When you use an immutable reference, you don't have this danger, so the compiler allows it.

You have discovered an important thing - Rust doesn't always care what you do in the function. When checking if a function call is valid, only the type signature of the function is used.

I'm sure there's a fancy way of saying this using the proper terms like *contravariance* and *covariance*, but I don't know those well enough to use them properly! ^_^

Comment: Thx a lot shepmaster! That really pins it down. I just received a similar hint from mkrasnenkov at the Rust user forum (not as detailed as yours) and was able to give a small summary of all 3 cases there.

Comment: In case 1, because of the &mut, 'c gets Foo's original lifetime. 'b is independent and does no harm.

In case 2, again because of the &mut, 'b gets Foo's original lifetime. This time, the &p is "too short" to fit into the &'b bool, hence "p does not live long enough".

In case 3, 'b is allowed to be shortened to &p's lifetime because there is no danger of test mutating _field to a reference that is "shorter" than the original Foo.

Hope, I understood correctly.